# Oracle apex dynamic action event after filter IR

Tags: dynamic, report, action, oracle-apex, interactive

I want to create a dynamic event after filtering or sorting an interactive report, but can't find the event what fits.
The goal is to run a javascript code after the user changed the filter/sorting in an interactive report.

I started with the Change event, but it's not for the filtering or sorting. 
Also tried with the Click event, but it's not applied for the filtering LOV.

Answer (score 2):

You're after the "After Refresh" dynamic action, associated with the IR region.

For example:
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2018/09/orcle-apex-hide-region-if-no-data-found.html

In Page Designer, right click on your region, create a DA, and that will be the default event type.